# How to use substring function to get last part of a word in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a list of emails I want to edit. I have a lot of emails with for example @institution.dk in the end. All these type of email I want to delete. The number of characters from left haven't got the same length, so therefore I must identify the emails from right to left.

I have tried:

```
data B;
set a;
where var not equals 'institution.dk';
run;
```

and

```
data B;
set a;
where var equals not 'institution.dk';
run;
```

and

```
data B;
set a;
where substr(var,-1,14^= 'institution.dk';
run;
```

and

```
data b;
set a;
var2=scan(trim(var),-1,14) ;
run;
data c;
set b;
if var2 ^= institution.dk;   
run;
```

But nothing Works. How do I get SAS to identify the last part of a string (Count from right to left), so I can remove these observations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be an index:

```
If index(var,"@institution.dk") then delete;
```

Another way would be to use a regex expression:

```
If prxmatch("#\@institution.dk#",var) then delete;
```

Another more useful way might be to use call scan:

```
Call scan(var,-1,pos,len,"@");
Var2=substr(var,pos);
If var2="institution.dk" then delete;
```

Line 1 creates pos and len variables for the last word after an @, line 2 creates a variable var2 containing that info, line 3 tests if it matches the string you want to exclude and deletes if that returns as true.

Answer (score 3):

Scan is the right place to start.  Emails can only have one '@', right?

```
email_account = scan(var,1,'@');
email_server = scan(var,2,'@');
```

Now you can filter how you want.  You don't need two steps like above:

```
data b;
  set a;
  length email_server $50;
  email_server = scan(var,2,'@');
  if email_server ne 'institution.dk';
run;
```

or

```
data b;
  set a;
  where scan(var,2,'@') ne 'institution.dk';
run;
```

There's also a useful LIKE operator in SQL/WHERE (but not IF or other SAS data step elements).  '%' is wildcard here.

```
data b;
  set a;
  where not (var like '%@institution.dk');
run;
```